# How do I fix this stack overflow error in my code below?

Tags: java

I am trying to find the square of a number using the scanner method but keep getting a 
stackflow error. I am new to programming will be glad if someone helps me out.
 My code is as below

```
import java.util.Scanner;


interface Number {
    int findSqr(int i);  // Returns the square of n
}


//a class A which implements the interface Number. 

 class A implements Number {


   public int findSqr(int i) {

       return findSqr(i);

   }
}

public class Question5_1{ 
        public static void main (String[] args){ 
          A a = new A();   // an object of class A
           // Reading a number from the keyboard
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
           int i = sc.nextInt();
           System.out.print(a.findSqr(i)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Fix your infinite recursion. `findSqr()` calls itself... recursion must have some case that doesn't return recursively if you'd like it to ever finish running.

Comment: Why are you returning findSqr(i); in your findSqr function? I don't see why you need recursion here, when you can simply return i * i

Answer (score 0):

Fix the line which invokes the function recursively `return findSqr(i)` with `return i * i` as follows --

```
public int findSqr(int i) {
    return i * i;
}
```

Comment: Ok it worked. That was great.It was the piece which was missing in my code. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

What you did there is an infinite recursion. The bit where it says

```
public int findScr(int i) {
    return findSqr(i)
}
```

essentially calls the very same method an infinite number of times in the return statement.
What happens is, that you execute the method, and it tries to return an integer. What you wrote though is a return statement that "returns" another call of the same method, so it gets executed again. Then the whole thing starts over again, so you get a StackOverflow.

Since there is no other code present, I have no idea what you are actually trying to do, but the `return findSqr(i)` line is what causes the problem.

Initially, recursion may be a rather complicated subject to really wrap you head around, I suggest you either avoid it for now (although it enables you to solve many problems in a really elegant way) or try to understand it a bit better maybe. I'd suggest the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) about recursion, although it gets complicated quite fast, or any other tutorial on it, just look it up on Google.

Comment: I had to specify a formula in the method body instead of calling the method again. I did not realize that earlier but I now do and it's working .